# How do detect if a character is not supported by my android phone?

Tags: android, encoding, character, currency, symbols

The encoding of some uncommon symbols is giving me problems, for instance the currency symbol of philippines is ₱, but in my phone it is displayed as "â,± 0,00".

So my question is, is it possible to check if a symbol is not supported in order to display something else? Or is there maybe a better option?

Comment: it is an encoding issue. post the code that displays that symbol

Comment: is it coming from webservice response ?

Comment: The code is minimal, something like this:
String symbol = "₱"
EditText edit.setText(symbol);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the computer used to compile the projects. I had no problems what so ever with the symbol when I ran the project on my OSX-machine, but when using the computer which was running on Windows the encoding started behaving weirdly. I was also using two separate android phones which led me to believe that was the problem, but it was never the phone's fault.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "\u20B1" as literal - may be problem lies within source file encoding.

As far as i know there are no simple way to get information if specific char is present inside font. But if the symbol is unsupported it should be rendered as single char (box or something).

About hard way - get font source file (may be phone should be routed) and parse it. Or try to render symbol to temporary buffer and analyze if it similar to some clearly unsupported symbol.